# How to access source code in bitbucket using REST API?

Tags: java, git, rest, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

How to access a java file which is sitting in repo in a specific package.
Bit bucket has meta data info like pullrequest api,last commit REST APIs.
can you suggest/help me with sample rest call and also how to pass username and password? given that I know fully qualified class name including project.

note: we are using bitbucket which hosted with our organization.

Ex: https://bitbucket.org/repo/my-project
branch: tempBranch
file:src/main/java/temp/Main.java

I would like to access/view full content on Main.java with in the Rest call.
is there  any REST api exist for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely there is no way to do this using the latest version (2.0) of the bitbucket.org (cloud) API.

The available data from the [`/repositories/{username}/{repo}`](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D) endpoint may lead you to somewhere.

You can access files in the 'downloads' of your repo using the [`/repositories/{username}/{repo}/downloads/{filename}`](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/downloads/%7Bfilename%7D) endpoint.

---

However [There is an endpoint for what you need in version 1.0 of the API](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/src-resources-296095214.html). Based on testing this still works.

Answer (score 0):

It is available (aug 2022) - see [Get file or directory contents](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-source/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-src-commit-path-get)

Implementation as follows - `# GET /2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/src/{commit}/{path}` 
create app password for the user, if you have pipeline `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` in the source, then you can save it using:

```
$pairCloud         = "{... your user ...}:{... your app password ...}" 
$credentialsCloud  = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($pairCloud))
$headersBasicCloud = @{"accept" = "application/json"; "authorization" = "Basic $credentialsCloud"} 
$bbCloudApi2Url    = "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0"

$workspace = "... put your workspace ..."
$repo      = "... put your repo_slug ..."
$commit    = "... put your commit ..."

$pplUrl    = "$bbCloudApi2Url/repositories/$workspace/$repo/src/$commit/bitbucket-pipelines.yml"

$ymlppl  = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $pplUrl -Headers $headersBasicCloud
$ymlppl.Content | Out-File "bitbucket-pipelines.yml"
```